# given two directory trees how to find which files are the same?

Tags: linux, bash, diff

I am writing a bash script, and I would like to know which files are the same in two directory  trees.

It would be the opposite of using diff.

Well i found the answer myself. I had tried it before, but I thought it did not work.

```
diff -srq dir1/ dir2/ | grep identical
```

Comment: For what application of `same`? Name? Inode? Size? Content? Mod Time? Owner? Group? Permissions?

Comment: Post your findings as an answer

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Well i found the answer myself. I had tried it before, but I thought it did not work.

```
diff -srq dir1/ dir2/ | grep identical
```

What **-srq** means? From **diff  --help** :

```
-s  --report-identical-files  Report when two files are the same.
-r  --recursive  Recursively compare any subdirectories found.
-q  --brief  Output only whether files differ.
```

Comment: Nice. How would you do it if want to consider only certain files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350039/given-two-directory-trees-how-to-find-which-filenames-are-the-same-considering

Comment: `Report when two files are the same` how to consider only file names?

Answer (score 23):

You can use a utility like *fdupes* or *rdfind* to list duplicate files. For example:

```
fdupes --recurse dir1 dir2
```

You might also want to use the `--sameline` flag to list all duplicates on the same line, rather than in text blocks, depending on how you want to parse the results.

Comment: This technique also detects identical files with different names. Not sure if diff can be tweaked to do the same

Comment: `fdupes` will also report duplicate files *within one tree*. There seems to be no option to disable that.