# Given two directory trees how to find which filenames are the same, considering only filenames satisfying a condition?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10087571/8565438) tells me how to find the files with the same filename in two directories in bash:

```
diff -srq dir1/ dir2/ | grep identical
```

Now I want to consider files which satisfy a condition. If I use  `ls E*`, I get back files starting with E. I want to do the same with the above command: give me the filenames which are different in `dir1/` and `dir2/`, but consider only those starting with E.

I tried the following:

```
diff -srq dir1/E* dir2/E* | grep identical
```

but it did not work, I got this output:

> diff: extra operand '/home/pal/konkoly/c6/elesbe3/1/EPIC_212291374- 
>   c06-k2sc.dat.flag.spline' diff: Try 'diff --help' for more
>   information.

((`/home/pal/konkoly/c6/elesbe3/1/EPIC_212291374- 
    c06-k2sc.dat.flag.spline` is a file in the so-called `dir1`, but `EPIC_212291374- 
    c06-k2sc.dat.flag.spline` is not in the so-called `dir2`))

How can I solve this?

---

I tried doing it in the following way, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28205822/8565438):

```
DIR1=$(ls dir1)
DIR2=$(ls dir2)

for i in $DIR1; do
    for j in $DIR2; do
        if [[ $i == $j ]]; then
            echo "$i == $j"
        fi
    done
done
```

It works as above, but if I write `DIR1=$(ls path1/E*)` and `DIR2=$(ls path2/E*)`, it does not, I get no output.

Comment: "it did not work" isn't exactly a problem statement -- show what output you got!  (that said, I know what output you got because it expanded to something like `diff -srq dir1/E1 dir1/E2 dir1/E3 dir2/E1 dir2/E2 dir2/E3`) -- you might try looking through `diff --help` or `man diff`.  `--exclude` is probably what you're looking for

Comment: I look it up. Edited the question according to your comment, thanks.

Comment: Are you actually dealing with directory trees or do you just have a flat list of files? And do you want to compare file contents or only the names of files?

Comment: I have two only two flat list of files, in two different directories. I care only about those which satisfy the condition (in this case starting with E). And I'd like to consider only name of files, not contents, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but I'd try something like:

```
comm -12 <(cd dir1 && ls E*) <(cd dir2 && ls E*)
```

Basic idea:

- Generate a list of filenames  in `dir1` that satisfy our condition. This can be done with `ls E*` because we're only dealing with a flat list of files. For subdirectories and recursion we'd use `find` instead (e.g. `find . -name 'E*' -type f`).
- Put the filenames in a canonical order (e.g. by sorting them). We don't have to do anything here because `E*` expands in sorted order anyway. With `find` we might have to pipe the output into `sort` first.
- Do the same thing to `dir2`.
- Only output lines that are common to both lists, which can be done with `comm -12`.

  `comm` expects to be passed two filenames on the command line, so we use the `<( ... )` bash feature to spawn a subprocess and connect its output to a named pipe; the name of the pipe can then be given to `comm`.

Comment: `comm -12 <(ls dir1/*) <(ls dir2/*)` gives the output: comm:

`file 2 is not in sorted order
comm: file 1 is not in sorted order`

`comm -12 <(ls dir1/E*) <(ls dir2/E*)` gives no output. Otherwise seems good, maybe its sth wrong with my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works fine. Though if someone needs a python implementation, this also works:

```
import glob

dir1withpath=glob.glob("path/to/dir1/E*")
dir2withpath=glob.glob("path/to/dir2/E*")

dir1=[]
for index,each in enumerate(dir1withpath):
    dir1list=dir1withpath[index].split("/")
    dir1.append(dir1list[-1])

dir2=[]
for index,each in enumerate(dir2withpath):
    dir2list=dir2withpath[index].split("/")
    dir2.append(dir2list[-1])

for each1 in dir1:
    for each2 in dir2:
        if each1 == each2:
            print(each1 + "is in both directories")
```